# Why does wcf web service hosted in iis over ssl. result in "403 forbidden"? Jquery $.post sends OPTIONS verb?

Tags: jquery, wcf, iis, ssl, http-status-code-403

I have a WCF Webservice hosted in IIS.  It uses a webHttpBinding.  There are WebInvoke attributes on the methods so that they can be access REST style.  I can successfully use them like so:
http://mydomain.com/MyService.svc/some/rest/style/thing
and POST to that the arguments to the web service.

Now I want to change this to HTTPS over a nonstandard port 7777.  I configured IIS correctly, got the cert and everything.  I can access html pages over https://mydomain.com:7777.
I added a modified the webhttpbinding to add a security node like so:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
</security>
```

I also changed my behavior's servicemetadata node and removed httpGetEnabled='true' and added httpsGetEnabled='true'

I can access https://mydomain.com:7777/MyService.svc and get a screen of info.

I can access https://mydomain.com:7777/MyService.svc/some/rest/style/thing using http get and i get a "Method not allowed" message.

BUT If I try to access https://mydomain.com:7777/MyService.svc/some/rest/style/thing with a POST I get a 403 forbidden

---

update some more info

I'm narrowing down the problem

I am using jQuery and accessing the webservice via a $.post("http://mydomain.com/.....". "data", callback, "json")..that worked
now I am doing $.post("https://mydomain.com:7777/.....". "data", callback, "json")..and that gives me a 403...using firebug I see instead of sending a POST, it is sending OPTIONS initially..and that is what is giving the 403

this might be a jquery problem

Answer (score 1):

JQuery $.ajax, $.get, $.post calls dont allow cross-domain calls. When you do make one, it sends OPTIONS verb instead of the POST verb, though the request method is POST.

Other work around could be creating another sub-domain which points to IP address of the URL you want to actually invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **httpcfg** to get IIS to listen for SSL traffic on a non standard port.

Comment: actually I have IIS listening just fine..it turned out to be more of a jquery issue..why it sends an OPTIONS verb instead of a POST verb when doing cross domain POST's

Answer (score 0):

Puffpio:

Please check to ensure that you're appending the "callback=?" parameter to your request URI. Then you should be seeing the GET verb in your request header.

From the jQuery documentation [page](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback):

> *The callback takes the form "example.com?callback=?". jQuery
>   automatically replaces the '?' with a
>   random method name that doesn't clash
>   with the global scope. You do not have
>   to specify the method name yourself.*

Hope this helps,

Michael Ibarra

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MOZILLA fire fox as a browser then it preflight the request and send a request with OPTIONS verb and when server returns the 200 OK status then it request the actual data with the POST verb.

CROSS domain issue.

Intekhab

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had the same problem where Ajax calls using jQuery's .load function were returning 403 errors.  I had to go into the Home Directory on the IIS Manager's Default Web Site's properties and select Configuration and then edit the .cgi extension's properties so that it included the OPTION verb.  Finding your question and subsequent comment helped me resolve this quickly.